# Objective - C And SQLite - Database Locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

What motivates the occurs "Error database is locked" when ever I open and close the database and also finalize all statement?

Code:

```
//Opening database
if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open.");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Database opened.");
    }

//Performing operation
char * err;
    if(sqlite3_exec(database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"----> Could not perform operation on table people. Error %@ <----", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:err]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"----> Operation performed on table people <----");
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Once check wheather the data base has all the rights

Comment: Yes...I checked several times.

Comment: delete the database and create it again with other name

Comment: The problem still persists =/